# Prometheus config file with Puppet: how to handle quotes and brackets in yaml config file?

Tags: arrays, yaml, puppet, prometheus

I'm trying to write a Prometheus config with this module: https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-prometheus

But I can't seem to get it to generate a valid relabeling config for Prometheus.

This is the relevant part of my current config:

```
'relabel_configs' => [
  {
    'source_labels' => '[__meta_consul_node]',
    'regex'         => '^(.*)$',
    'target_label'  => 'instance',
    'replacement'   => '$1',
  },
  {
    'source_labels' => '[__meta_consul_service]',
    'regex'         => '^(.*)$',
    'target_label'  => 'job',
    'replacement'   => '$1',
  }
],
```

This is what I get in my prometheus.yml:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: '[__meta_consul_node]'
    regex: ^(.*)$
    target_label: instance
    replacement: $1
  - source_labels: '[__meta_consul_service]'
    regex: ^(.*)$
    target_label: job
    replacement: $1
```

What I want is:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_node']
    regex: '^(.*)$'
    target_label: 'instance'
    replacement: '$1'
  - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_service']
    regex: '^(.*)$'
    target_label: 'job'
    replacement: '$1'
```

I tried a ton of things, but could not figure out how to format hash values in my manifest so that I would get the correct config file for Prometheus.

This seems to be a problem with the ruby parser? How do I escape the `'` correctly?

Comment: In YAML specifying this key-value pair: `regex: ^(.*)$` or this: `regex: '^(.*)$'` is exactly the same, because the first scalar value doesn't need quoting. The same holds for they KV pairs with keys `regex`, `target_labels`, and `replacement`. Adding quotes there absolutely makes no sense.  Only for `source_labels` you are changing the value from a scalar string that start and ends with a bracket to a list containing a single scalar string value. Why are you adding all this superflous quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here is how variable arrays are handled in Puppet and in YAML, and how strings are parsed in YAML.

In YAML, variable arrays can be:

```
array:
- element
- another_element
```

or:

```
array: [element, another_element]
```

In Puppet, they look like:

```
$array = [element, another_element]
```

Therefore, you can have a clean one-to-one mapping of the arrays by simply specifying an array of strings in your Puppet hash for the `source_labels` key like:

```
'relabel_configs' => [
  {
    'source_labels' => ['__meta_consul_node'], # single element string array
    'regex'         => '^(.*)$',
    'target_label'  => 'instance',
    'replacement'   => '$1',
  },
  {
    'source_labels' => ['__meta_consul_service'], # single element string array
    'regex'         => '^(.*)$',
    'target_label'  => 'job',
    'replacement'   => '$1',
  }
],
```

and this will correctly generate an array of strings for your `source_labels` as you described for what you desired.

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_node'] # single element string array
    regex: ^(.*)$
    target_label: instance
    replacement: $1
  - source_labels: ['__meta_consul_service'] # single element string array
    regex: ^(.*)$
    target_label: job
    replacement: $1
```

Note that the YAML will be parsed exactly the same for quoted and unquoted strings (e.g. `target_label: job` is the same as `target_label: 'job'`).